# foswiki: "Failure processing response from the repository search"

Tags: wiki

I'm checking for updates to my plugins by going to *configure ->    InstalledPlugins ->  review installed extensions* and I get a huge error message with red letters starting with "Failure processing response from the repository search: Failed to eval $VERSION from our $RELEASE = $VERSION;" and followed by a lot of lines about  plugins. The first plugin mentioned is "GlobalReplacePlugin"

My foswiki release is 2.1.2

Answer (score 0):

According to [gac410 on IRC](http://irclogs.foswiki.org/bin/irclogger_log/foswiki?date=2017-01-25,Wed&sel=45) *"some extension doesn't have a numeric string* [for VERSION or RELEASE]". In your case it's `GlobalReplacePlugin`.

Find a file named GlobalReplacePlugin.pm in your foswiki installation and edit it. E.g.:

```
cd /var/www/foswiki
find -name GlobalReplacePlugin.pm
   ./lib/Foswiki/Plugins/GlobalReplacePlugin.pm
vi ./lib/Foswiki/Plugins/GlobalReplacePlugin.pm
```

change the lines that read like this:

```
$VERSION = '$Rev: 2960 (2009-03-10) $'
$RELEASE=$Rev
```

to contain only the number like this:

```
our $VERSION = '2960';
our $RELEASE = '2960';
```

Hopefully it's a bug that will be fixed (in the same IRC I read "But really configure shold not crash [...] Configure really needs to tolerate the older extensions"